# Sectors for telecom radio towers

Tags: qgis

Based on [Creating sectors for telecom towers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/creating-sectors-for-telecom-towers/279381), I'm facing one problem after creating the site sectors.

I can sucessufuly create all sectors with shape tool. After that I save my project and everything is ok.
[image]

But if I close QGIS and reopen the project, my shape layer that should have all sectors, is now empty without features on attribute table. (image below)
[image]

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the quick [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format!

Comment: Looks like virtual layers >try save as *and set the CRS to the projection your are using.

Comment: It seems that in the answer presented by you shows a way to design point objects in the form of sectors of relay towers, you also need a tool to create sectors for some parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New layer creation on QGIS would be in temporary form (like new excel file without saving on system), need to save this newly generated layer to local system folder by right click on layer>>Export>>Save Features as>>Choose Format>>Choose file name>>Tick: Add saved file to map

If the work space is saved from QGIS (Cntl+S>>File on local system) it could easily restores the project with the previously saved settings.

[image]
[image]